# maven won't include all of ojdbc modules when running

Tags: maven, ojdbc

I am getting the following error when I attempt to javafx:run in maven.

```
[WARNING] Can't extract module name from oraclepki-19.3.0.0.jar: CertificateTest.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)
[WARNING] Some dependencies encountered issues while attempting to be resolved as modules and will not be included in the classpath; you can change this behavior via the  'includePathExceptionsInClasspath' configuration parameter.
```

oraclepki is part of ojdbc, which was imported through the following dependency:

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
      <version>19.3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

How would I resolve this issue? 
The warning says I can change the behavior through the 'includePathExceptionsInClasspath' configuration parameter, but I don't know where I would set that, and cannot find any explanations when googling it.
The IDE I am using is eclipse.

Comment: simple answer to this: you can't fix this. This is a really hard issue in the jar file which contains a class in default package which is never being allowed in java modules. This implies you are trying to use modules which will fail with this. Apart from that I have my doubts that the oracle jdbc driver supports the java module system correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Can you include the following dependency? If you look at the [POM](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/oracle/database/jdbc/ojdbc10/19.3.0.0/ojdbc10-19.3.0.0.pom), you will get oraclepki.jar, osdt_core.jar and osdt_cert.jar etc., Check out the [blog](https://medium.com/oracledevs/all-in-and-new-groupids-oracle-jdbc-drivers-on-maven-central-a76d545954c6?source=---------3------------------) for more details.

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.jdbc.database</groupId>
      <artifactId>ojdbc10</artifactId>
      <version>19.3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: 1st, I assume you mean com.oracle.database.jdbc (Its what is used in the POM you linked), 2nd, I get the same error whether I use this dependency or the one in my post.